# Show tooltip based on contents of children (innerHTML) with React

Tags: reactjs, children

I have a component called `Row` that is currently using `text-overflow: ellipsis` to avoid the row from wrapping when it is too long.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function Row(props) {
    const { show=true, children } = props;
    
    const style = {
        display: show ? 'block' : 'none',
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        textOverflow: 'ellipsis'
    };
    
    const title = React.Children
      .map(children, c => c.toString()) // wat do?
      .join(' ');
      
    return (<div style={style} title={title}>{children}</div>);
}

const el = document.querySelector('#content');

const component = (<div style={{width:'200px'}}>
  <Row>This is the first one works and is very long.</Row>
  <Row>The second one works too.</Row>
  <Row>But <b>bold</b> children do <b>not</b> work properly.</Row>
  <Row show={false}>A hidden row.</Row>
</div>);

ReactDOM.render(component, el);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<h1>Hover over the rows below</h1>
<div id="content"></div>
```

The `title` attribute can handle my tooltip but I don't know how to get the contents of the children when they are not text nodes.

My next thought is that I need to wait until the children have been rendered to the DOM and then add a `mouseover` event to retrieve the text nodes...but that seems like overkill.

How can I get the contents of the children as text nodes and display as a tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this by checking each child element in the `.map`, if it's an an object grab `props.children` and turn it into a string.

To make this work for deeply nested HTML you will need to go recursive. Some additional checks on what the element is (when it's not a string) would also be good.

```js
function Row(props) {
    const { show=true, children } = props;
    
    const style = {
        display: show ? 'block' : 'none',
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        textOverflow: 'ellipsis'
    };
    
    const title = React.Children
      .map(children, c => {
        if (typeof c === 'string') {
          return c.toString()
        } else {
          return c.props.children.toString();
        }

      }) // wat do?
      .join(' ');
      
    return (<div style={style} title={title}>{children}</div>);
}

const el = document.querySelector('#content');

const component = (<div style={{width:'200px'}}>
  <Row>This is the first one works and is very long.</Row>
  <Row>The second one works too.</Row>
  <Row>But <b>bold</b> children do <b>not</b> work properly.</Row>
  <Row show={false}>A hidden row.</Row>
</div>);

ReactDOM.render(component, el);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<h1>Hover over the rows below</h1>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: I flipped it like `if(typeof c==='object') recurse() else return c.toString()` which will cover number types and of course made it recursive and so far, so good!